# Formatting ordered dictionary that has lists for values

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dicionary that contains key:value pairs, I need to print these pairs but format the value field. It is currently outputting as follows

```
|key1| ['vl', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5']
|key2| ['v1', 'v2']
```

But I need this specific format

```
|key1| 'vl', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5'|
|key2| 'v1', 'v2'|
```

I am just doing a basic for loop to print the k:v but have no idea how to format as above.

```
    for key, value in sorted(dict.items()):
        print(key, value)
```

Comment: `print(key, ", ".join(value), "|")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
for key, value in sorted(dict.items()):
    print(key, str(value).replace("]", "|").replace("[",""))
```

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, never use python builtin keywords as variable names, so don't name your variable `dict`, but something else like `dct`

Iterate through the dictionary and print the string according to the given format.
You would need to create the string out of values such that the values are single quoted, and then you can use f-strings to create the final string

```
dct = {'key1': ['vl', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5'],
'key2': ['v1', 'v2']}

for key, value in sorted(dct.items()):
    #Convert list of values to given value string
    value_str = ', '.join("'{0}'".format(w) for w in value)

    #Use f-string to print
    print(f'|{key}| {value_str}|')
```

The output will be

```
|key1| 'vl', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5'|
|key2| 'v1', 'v2'|
```